# Best way to dot product of multiple large arrays numpy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a `numpy` of hundred thousands arrays with hundred thousands of items.

Currently, I created it using a sparse vector to represent the array, but I want:

```
my_array = np.array([
    [[0, 1.9], [2, 3.1], [99999, 0.1]],
    [[1, 2.6], [471, 2.21], [21827, 1.51]],...
])
```

I want to dot product each of the arrays given by a single array, lets say I got:

```
compare_array = np.array([[5, 9.1], [88, 5.1], [457, 0.12]])
```

What is the best way to get the dot product of `compare_array` to each element in `my_array`?

If I generate all the data of hundred thousands (`np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1., ...]])`) it will give the `out of memory error`, but if I compute with `for loop` and generate the hundred thousands array in the process, it will take `~75s` and that's to much time for me.

Here is the code I used for generate array and count the dot product right now:

```
def create_all_array(array):
    all_word_rep = np.zeros(100000)
    for idx, value in array:
        all_item_array[idx] = value
    return np.array(all_item_array)


dot_product = [np.dot(create_all_array(compare_array),
                           create_all_array(data)) for data in my_array]
```

Comment: Show your loopy code?

Comment: What is `each element in my_array`? Also as mentioned, please update your question with the code that you've tried before.

Comment: Can you give desired output given concrete inputs? I'm struggling to see what you are trying to do..